# How can I use Bokeh in an Azure ML notebook

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, azure-machine-learning-service

I can run the following code in a Jupyter notebook (Python 3.5) on my PC using Anaconda, and it works fine. But when I run the same code in an Azure ML notebook, I get the plot, but also the error message described below. Does anyone know how to use Bokeh in Azure ML notebooks ? Is there perhaps a way to import the seemingly missing module 'ipykernel'

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers

colormap = {'setosa': 'red', 'versicolor': 'green', 'virginica': 'blue'}
colors = [colormap[x] for x in flowers['species']]

p = figure(title = "Iris Morphology")
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Petal Length'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Petal Width'

p.circle(flowers["petal_length"], flowers["petal_width"],
     color=colors, fill_alpha=0.2, size=10)

output_notebook()
show(p)
```

produces the plot, but also the following errors

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-c50d1a94007e> in <module>()
 13 
 14 output_notebook()
---> 15 show(p)

/home/nbuser/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bokeh/io.py in show(obj,        browser, new)
    299 
    300     '''
--> 301     return _show_with_state(obj, _state, browser, new)
    302 
    303 def _show_with_state(obj, state, browser, new):

/home/nbuser/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bokeh/io.py in     _show_with_state(obj, state, browser, new)
    307 
    308     if state.notebook:
--> 309         comms_handle = _show_notebook_with_state(obj, state)
    310 
    311     elif state.server_enabled:

/home/nbuser/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bokeh/io.py in     _show_notebook_with_state(obj, state)
    329         comms_target = make_id()
    330         publish_display_data({'text/html': notebook_div(obj,   comms_target)})
--> 331         handle = _CommsHandle(get_comms(comms_target), state.document,     state.document.to_json())
    332         state.last_comms_handle = handle
    333         return handle

/home/nbuser/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bokeh/util/notebook.py in   get_comms(target_name)
    109 
    110     '''
--> 111     from ipykernel.comm import Comm 
    112     return Comm(target_name=target_name, data={})
    113 

ImportError: No module named 'ipykernel'

In [16]:
```

​

Answer (score 2):

There are two options I think. In a notebook, I think you can use `conda` to install new packages in your AzureML environment, by executing a cell with the following:

```
!conda install ipykernel --yes
```

Note the `!` at the beginning. In Jupyter notebooks that means to execute the command as a shell command.

Althernatively, in the upcoming `0.12.2` release later this week *(today's date: 2016-08-28)* the "notebook comms" feature that uses `ipykernel` to be imported will no longer be "turned on" all the time, and will only be used when explicitly asked for. That should also resolve this problem.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the !conda comand. It seems to be working now (even without the !conda install ) so I guess the 0.12.2 version is installed (today is 2016-08-31). However after displaying the graph, the whole notebook now becomes unresponsive and not even a kernel restart will bring it back to life...

Comment: `0.12.2` is not released yet, and I would say it is doubtful that you have a "developer preview build" installed unless you have explicitly done so yourself. For reference, the installed version can be checked by examining `bokeh.__version__`. Also just to be completely clear, `conda` is a shell command line tool, and the `!` is a special Jupyter notebook way to execute shell commands from within the notebook.

Answer (score 1):

@MortenBunesGustavsen, As I known, there are two different versions of python for Azure ML notebook which include `python3.4` on the `env3` host and `python3.5` on the `anaconda3_410` host. You can directly access the url `http://notebooks.azure.com` to use the `Bokeh` without any errors on the `python3.5` environment with `ipykernel`, not access the jupyter (python3.4 without ipykernel) from Azure ML studio.

Please check the runtime version via the code below first.

```
In [1]: import sys
In [2]: sys.version
Out[2]: '3.5.1 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jun 15 2016, 15:32:45) \n[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That worked, thanks !
Do you know how/if I can import a dataset from my Azure ML account to a Jupyter notebook in this environment ?

Comment: just found ut that I can import data the same way as in the other Jupyter environment... via the azureml.Workspace command.